# Unexpected data format from LinkedIn Profile API endpoint

Tags: list, dictionary, linkedin-api, endpoint

When using the LinkedIn Profile API endpoint with `fields=urn:li:fs_oilCompany&format=json`, I'm receiving a nested list of dictionary objects instead of the expected single dictionary object containing the oil company data.

Followed the LinkedIn API documentation for the Profile endpoint, specifying the `urn:li:fs_oilCompany` field in the fields parameter and setting the format to JSON. Then made the API call using my authorized access token.
I Expected to receive a single dictionary object containing the requested oil company details, such as name, location, and website.

Instead of the expected single dictionary, I received a nested list containing a single dictionary with the oil company data. This makes it difficult to access the data directly and requires additional processing to extract the desired information.